# How to write a Roslyn Code Analyzer to prevent bad logging practices

Tags: c#, roslyn, roslyn-code-analysis

I would like to help prevent our dev team from not using our structured logging set up. The correct way to log (for us) would be like this:

```
_logger.LogInformation("This is a message template with a {@StructuredField}", structuredFieldVariable);
```

An incorrect way to log it would be like this:

```
_logger.LogInformation($"this is a poorly constructed log message with a {variable} in the template");
```

I'm thinking a roslyn code analyzer could be written to check if any string interpolation is being done inside of `_logger.LogInformation()`. Would this be possible/feasible?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, it’s certainly possible. But your question is really broad. There are a lot of tutorials and videos on creating Roslyn code analyzers online, including many from Microsoft. Have you followed any of those? Stack Overflow is better suited for addressing more targeted or specific coding questions you might run into while trying to implement a code analyzer, rather than taking on the task for you.

Comment: I think you can also use SonarQube for this scenario, and use roslyn too. Look at this link for more information: [Add Rules](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/extend/adding-coding-rules/)

Comment: It's possible to check string interpolation. But why is that necessary? Is it just about code style? If the second overload can't be used, why create a public method for _logger?

Comment: @joe You should never use default string interpolation/formatting for structured log events. It breaks the templating and filtering capabilities on the messages. https://nblumhardt.com/2015/01/c-6-string-interpolation-and-serilog/

That article also applies to the Microsoft logging abstractions.